# Get rid of use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB statement in repository classes

Tags: php, laravel, repository-pattern, lumen

I use the repository pattern in lumen together with Query Builder. The repository classes look generally like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Repositories;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class RepoNameRepository {
    public function methodName() {
        /* 
        Various Calls to the DB facade...
        $data = DB::table("tableName")...->get(); 
        */
        return $data;
    }   
}
```

Is there any efficient way to *get rid of the* *use statement* **use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB** at the beginning of each of my repository classes? Ideally, the DB facade would just be available as is in web.php.

What I could think of so far is to have a Repository base class with the use statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is how PHP works.

Your alternatives are to use the alias:

```php
use DB;
```

Or prefix your calls with a backslash so it looks in the root namespace.

```php
\DB::table('users');
```

Comment: Where does the DB alias get defined?

Comment: Most, if not all, `Facades` aliases are defined in `config/app.php` under `aliases`, you can even add your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `app()` helper function with the `'db'` [service container binding key](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/facades#facade-class-reference):

```php
$data = app('db')->table('tableName')...->get();
```

It doesn't require any `use` statement.

Comment: If app() is globally avaible in the repository classes, is there really no way to achieve the same for DB::table() ? :)

Comment: `app()` is a function, `DB` is a class. Unqualified functions resolve to global functions, Unqualified classes resolve to current namespace, see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php), so you have to use `\DB::table()` as @Dwight correctly explained. If you use `DB::table()` without a `use` php searches in the current namespace.